# How to initialize a global variable only once in typescript

Tags: variables, typescript, global

I need to make "tokens" a global variable that will be initialized on the first call using the init() function.

Q1. How can I initialize the variable using init()? What is the best practice to initialize a global variable in TypeScript?

Q2. As this variable is initialized from a json file, how can I make it initialized ONLY once during the lifetime of my application? So if I import this variable in different files, I don't want to read the json file again.

```
export var tokens: Token[] = [];

function init() {
    if (tokens) return; // already initialized
    let tokensJson = fs.readFileSync("./lib/data/tokens.json", "utf8");
    let tokensData = JSON.parse(tokensJson);
    for (var i = 0; i < tokensData.length; i++) {
        tokens.push(new Token(tokensData[i].name, tokensData[i].type));
    }
}
```

Client code:

file1.ts

```
import { tokens } from "./tokens";
for (var i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++) 
    ...
```

file2.ts

```
import { tokens } from "./tokens";
for (var i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++) 
    ...
```

I really appreciate if you could give me an idea or best pattern of creating global or static module variables that will be initialized once but can be used from different files in TypeScript.

Answer (score 3):

The top level code that of a module will executed exactly once - when the module is loaded for the first time. At least that's the case for CommonJS modules, but I think for the other types too.

If you import the module for the second time the script in the module definition won't be executed again, and the returned exports from the first run will be reused.

That means you could do:

```
export var tokens: Token[] = [];

function init() {
    let tokensJson = fs.readFileSync("./lib/data/tokens.json", "utf8");
    let tokensData = JSON.parse(tokensJson);
    for (var i = 0; i < tokensData.length; i++) {
        tokens.push(new Token(tokensData[i].name, tokensData[i].type));
    }
}

init()
```

Or you could even omit the init function declaration and put the content directly into the module. Or use an immediate invoked function if you don't like the init name but still want scoping for the temporary variables.

In your case a single expression would also work:

```
export var tokens = 
  JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("./lib/data/tokens.json", "utf8"))
  .map(td => new Token(td.name, td.type));
```